# How to write short non-element-specific jquery? Duplicate code headache

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having to duplicate code for each element. Here's an example, which on enter press says if the input element has a certain left-margin, which then moves the first input away and displays the second [.next()] .. and then third / fourth etc from there - with unwanted duplicate code.

```
var input1 = $(".input-one");
var input2 = $(".input-two");

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { // on enter press
        if ($(input1).css("margin-left") === "-232px") { // if input has this margin
            $(input1).css({"margin-left":"-1200px","opacity":"0"}); // move input left and fade out                 
            $(input1).next().css({"display":"block"}); // show next input
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(input1).next().css({"margin-left":"-232px","opacity":"1"}); // animate next input in
            }, 40);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(input1).next().focus() // focus next input
                $(input1).css({"display":"none"}); // hides first input after fade out
            }, 600);
        }
        if ($(input2).css("margin-left") === "-232px") {
            // DUPLICATE CODE WOULD BE HERE
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried:

```
var input1 = $("#input-container").children();
```

but this applies css properties to all the children on enter press, which is unwanted. I need something like:

```
if ($(input1).css("margin-left") === "-232px") { // if input has this margin
    $(this input1).css({"margin-left":"-1200px","opacity":"0"}); // affect only the initial if input NOT all of the children
```

but that's where my knowledge ends. I'd like to not duplicate code and write this to work for each input change, affecting on the current input with the -232px margin-left.

Hope this makes sense, and many thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$("#input-container").find('input');` if you want further filtering of input textfields then use `$("#input-container").find('input[type="text"]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them all in a single jQuery object, then use `.each()` to apply your logic to each of them in turn:

```
var elements = $('#input-container').children();

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { // on enter press
        elements.each(function() {
            var $input = $(this); // the specific element for this iteration
            if ($input.css("margin-left") === "-232px") { // if input has this margin
                $input.css({"margin-left":"-1200px","opacity":"0"}); // move input left and fade out                 
                $input.next().css({"display":"block"}); // show next input
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $input.next().css({"margin-left":"-232px","opacity":"1"}); // animate next input in
                }, 40);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $input.next().focus() // focus next input
                    $input.css({"display":"none"}); // hides first input after fade out
                }, 600);
            }
        });
    }
});
```